# ORA-01555: snapshot too old error when deleting with transactions

Tags: oracle, plsql

I hope someone can explain me why I'm seeing ORA-01555. I have a function and a procedure to perform a cleanup in a huge table:

```
-- Small cleanup in separate transaction.
FUNCTION clean_single(ts_until IN TIMESTAMP, datapoint_id IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM VALUES WHERE DATAPOINT_ID = datapoint_id AND TS < ts_until;
    COMMIT;
    RETURN sql%rowcount;
END clean_single;

PROCEDURE prc_clean IS
    count_all_deleted_vals NUMBER(10) := 0;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        FOR dps IN (
            SELECT x AS dpid, y as tsUntil FROM Z where some conditions
            LOOP
                count_all_deleted_vals := count_all_deleted_vals + clean_single(dps.tsUntil, dps.dpid);
            END LOOP;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Removed ' || count_all_deleted_vals || ' values');
    END;
END prc_clean;
```

The idea is to run `prc_clean()` from a job and after the relevant datapoint ids are selected, the deletion per datapoint-id is done in a single transaction to avoid having one huge transaction.

But when I run this it runs for a while and then fails with ORA-01555.
In detail i do not understand why this is happening. Why does the `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;` in the function not prevent this?
What can I do to prevent it?

Comment: The "PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION" (PAT) is of no use in this case, there is a function that commits, so the transaction is complete. Adding the pragma is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, cause of ORA-01555 is often committing within a loop - and that's exactly what you're doing.

Skip the function altogether (doing DML in it is usually wrong anyway) and use only procedure, e.g.

```
PROCEDURE prc_clean
IS
   count_all_deleted_vals  NUMBER (10) := 0;
BEGIN
   FOR dps IN (SELECT x AS dpid, y AS tsUntil
                 FROM Z
                WHERE some conditions)
   LOOP
      DELETE FROM VALUES
            WHERE     DATAPOINT_ID = dps.dpid
                  AND TS < dps.tsuntil;

      count_all_deleted_vals := count_all_deleted_vals + SQL%ROWCOUNT;
   END LOOP;

   COMMIT;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Removed ' || count_all_deleted_vals || ' values');
END;
```